# WCF, active directory authentication|authorization and user profiles in sql combination

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, active-directory

I'm developing a WCF service that will host business logic of the application. The application is mostly for intranet, but can be accessed from internet. We have an active directory domain up and running, so I plan to authenticate and authorize users according to their username and groups they are in. This service will be used mostly be an ASP.NET MVC site

So, first question is how to authenticate and authorize users based on their AD profile?

Secondly, I need to store additional info about each user. The problem is that I can't modify AD scheme. The number of added fields is about 10 or so.

Can I somehow use SQL server for profile storage? Of course I can, but how to tie this with AD auth?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WIF for this.

You would configure your WCF service for WIF in the normal way and then use a custom `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` class deriving from the base `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` and overriding its `Authenticate` method. This is a normal extensibility point of WIF. WIF will
get hold of the security token from the incoming request and add claims for each of the relevant AD properties. In your override of the Authenticate method, you will add new claims to represent your extra properties.

The basic use of WIF for WCF services is described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748476.aspx

To see how to use ClaimsAuthenticationManager, start here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748211.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you have a couple of choices here, but you will have to carefully consider the implementation.

The primary issue with using active directory authentication is that by default a user's credentials can only be passed successfully between two machines. In the case of a web application, this means that the user's credentials can travel between the end user's machine and the web server, but no further.

However, this behavior can be changed through the use of Kerberos authentication, which essentially allows an authentication ticket to be passed among all of the trusted machines in the chain (i.e. from the web server to the application server to the database, for example). Successfully configuring Kerberos can be extremely challenging, especially if you have had no prior experience with it.

I think your best bet is to configure your web site to accept only Windows Authentication. This means that IIS will perform the validation of the user against active directory. In your ASP.Net application you can pickup the domain name of the authorized user from Request.ServerVariables("logon_user").

At this point, you can log the user on with FormsAuthentication, for example, without requiring them to login again.

You could then either implement the SQL Server Membership Provider or create your own interface to your database for further user validation and extra information storage. We have used both mechanisms, but I prefer the self-built one due to the additional control it provides and, in this case, you won't need a lot of the functionality (password reset, recovery, etc) that the membership provider offers.